# To overcome iteration limit and trying to speed up

Tags: matrix, warning-messages, list-manipulation

I have a program and I need to take the `Dot` product of many matrices, which is quite effectively working for small NStep. But for large(=30000), it is failing and saying. Either I use `ParallelTable` or not, problem remains.

```
$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.
```

This is my program,

```
a = 1;
tI = 0.0001;
dt = 0.0001;
NStep=30000;
T1[t_] = j1 (Cos[t]); 

T2[t_] = j2 ;

cond = {j1 -> 0.9, j2 -> 1.};
HSm[t_] = ({{0, -(T1[t] + T2[t] Cos[k])}, {-(T1[t] + T2[t] Cos[k]),0}})//. cond;
HStDig[t_] = MatrixExp[t *DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[HSm[t]]]]


us = ParallelTable[HStDig[tI + j dt], {j, 0, NStep}];
us1 = Apply[Dot, us];
```

How to go about it? Is there a way to speed up the program?

Comment: Isn't the `MatrixExp` of a diagonal matrix just the diagonal matrix made up of the elements of that matrix exponentiated? You might save some time putting that in explicitly rather than using `MatrixExp`.

Comment: @march great idea. Thanks

Comment: I think the big issue is that you're trying to multiply 30000 *expressions* rather than 3000 *numbers* (since `k` is left as a symbol). This is going to be tough for *Mathematica*'s symbolic processing. I would recommend choosing a value for `k`, and then doing the multiplication. Finally, since matrix multiplication of diagonal matrices is the same as element-wise multiplication of the matrices, do `Times@@us` rather than `Dot@@us`. If you insist on using `Dot`, you can do `Block[{$IterationLimit = 30002}, Dot @@ us]`, but it will take longer than the `Times` method.

Comment: Once again thanks @march. Let me go through it meticulously. `k` is supposed to be given value from a list of numbers

Answer (score 4):

To answer the specific question, I think that instead of `Apply[Dot, l]`,
`Fold[Dot, l]` will not run into any problems. Of course, all the other comments are valid.