# Matrix Exponentiation

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

This is in continuation [with this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/142041/to-overcome-iteration-limit-and-trying-to-speed-up) but it is more general. I will try to make it self contained.

I have a program and I need to take the `Dot` product of many matrices. But while taking the `MatrixExp`, I am facing the numeric problem(which I am familiar with, unfortunately don't know how to go out of it). However, I come up with one technique(not good at all).

```
MatrixExp::eivn: Incorrect number 0 of eigenvectors for eigenvalue -1. Sqrt[1.405 E^(2 I k)+0.9 E^(I k) Cos[t]+0.9 E^(3 I k) Cos[t]+0.405 E^(2 I k) Cos[2. t]] with multiplicity 1.
```

This is my program,

```
a = 1;
tI = 0.0001;
dt = 0.0001;
NStep=30000;
T1[t_] = j1 (Cos[t]); 

T2[t_] = j2 ;

cond = {j1 -> 0.9, j2 -> 1.};
HSm[t_,k_] = ({{0, -(T1[t] + T2[t] Cos[k])}, {-(T1[t] + T2[t] Cos[k]),0}})//. cond;
HStDig[t_, k_Real] = MatrixExp[HSm[t,k]]


us = ParallelTable[(tI + j dt) * HStDig[tI + j dt,k], {j, NStep, 0, -1}];
us1 = Apply[Dot, us];
```

How to go about this problem? Is there a way to speed up the program?

Note:
Diagonalization can't be taken for the matrix!
`k` is supposed to be given value from a list of numbers

Comment: The matrix exponential of your matrix can be computed by hand and gives you a matrix with `Cosh` and `Sinh` in its components. This might speed up the computation.

Comment: @marmot I didn't get.

Comment: Try `FullSimplify[MatrixExp[mat]]` where `mat={{0,a},{a,0}}`. Your matrix is of this type. 
Another problem of your code is that you add the scalar `tI` to a matrix.

Comment: @marmot I edited my question, thanks for the valuable points. Let me go through them

Comment: If you use `HStDig[t_, k_] = FullSimplify[MatrixExp[HSm[t, k]]]` your code works.

Comment: @marmot I liked though but is not solving the problem at all.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but in my case the error messages you receive do not show up.

Comment: @marmot which version? In my case error remains. Can you just show the code photo as a link? I am sure I am making some mistake.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 11.1.0.0 on MacOS and the only modification I did to your code is `HStDig[t_, k_] = FullSimplify[MatrixExp[HSm[t, k]]]` instead of  `HStDig[t_, k_Real] = MatrixExp[HSm[t,k]]`. Unfortunately I do not know how to upload screenshots in comments,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56729/discussion-between-l-k-and-marmot).